# UISearch Bar in ios 8

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

I am getting JSONArray data and show phone numbers in table
I am using UISearchBar in UITableView.

When I am type in search bar it reload data and show type value in first cell.

But i clicked first cell means it show  old array value.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   if (isSearching) 
   {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
   }
   else 
   {
        cell.textLabel.text = [phoneNoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   }
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText 
{
   [searchResultArray removeAllObjects];
   if([searchText length] != 0)
   {
        isSearching = YES;
        [self searchTableList];
   }
   else 
   {
        isSearching = NO;
   }
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    tempString = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you set isSearching to yes. Now datasoucre of table has changed. and you have reloaded the data.

and you are supposed to update your datasource methods as well

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (isSearching) {
    return [searchResultArray count];
}
else
{
  return [phoneNoArray count];
 }
}
```

HTH